# My robots.txt is User-agent: * Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /*/_/ what its means?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a Google site, and today I found google generated a new robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /feeds/
Disallow: /*/_/
```

What does it mean? Your kind reply is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the breakdown:

```
User-agent: *  -- Apply to all robots 
Disallow: /feeds/  -- Do not crawl the /feeds/ directory
Disallow: /*/_/  -- Do not crawl any subdirectory that is named _
```

For more information, see [www.robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

The `User-Agent` header is how browsers and robots identify themselves.

The `Disallow` lines define the rules the robots are supposed to follow - in this case what they shouldn't crawl.

Comment: Thanks for yours answer.But this is something bad or not for me? Because Google automatically generates my robots.txt and they're doing what they want.
Many thanks!

Comment: @Roland - you need to look at these rules, see what files are not indexed as a result and decide if this is content you _do_ or _do not_ want indexed. If it isn't (or you don't have these directories), then these rules are fine.